# What is the ActivityType when handling the launch of a complication with onContinueUserActivity in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I have a SwiftUI Apple Watch app. When a user taps on a complication, I want to show the appropriate view. I think I can do so with an onContinueUserActivity modifier but I can't find the appropriate ActivityType.

I named it `CLKComplicationTapActivityType` below but I need the real constant.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        StationList()
            .onContinueUserActivity(CLKComplicationTapActivityType, perform: handleComplicationTap)
    }
    
    func handleComplicationTap(_ userAcivity: NSUserActivity){
        if let date = userAcivity.userInfo?[CLKLaunchedTimelineEntryDateKey]{
            \\ handle the tap
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationdescriptor/3612140-useractivity

> When the user taps on a complication specified by this configuration,
> the system launches the app and calls handle(_:), passing the user
> activity.

You can define your own custom activity:

```
let YourActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.foo.customconstant")
```

And then assign it to the `userActivity` property of the `CLKComplicationDescriptor` that you return in `CLKComplicationDataSource.getComplicationDescriptors(handler:)`.